# Strange syntactic behaviour

Tags: jquery

I encountered a very weird issue today.

The following code doesn't work:

```
export default function initButtonControl(container) {
    const find = (container === $ ? $ : container.find);

    find('button').on('click', function() {
        console.log('hey!');
    });
}
initButtonControl($('.container'));
```

I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at find

But this one do the job:

```
export default function initButtonControl(container) {
    const buttons = (container === $ ? $('button') : container.find('button'));

    buttons.on('click', function() {
        console.log('hey!');
    });
}
initButtonControl($('.container'));
```

Why?

In the two case, I have `container !== $`. `$` is referring to jQuery.

In the hope you will help me understand, thanks :)

Comment: because find is a function not a property

Comment: `$` is referring to jQuery, `container` to `$('.container')`

Comment: but that's not how jquery works...

Comment: when would a container ever equal `$`? it doesn't because it never equals jquery. `$` is the same as `jQuery`. `$('.element')` makes it a jquery object ..

Comment: Thus how jQuery works? Please explain it to me.

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library that for the most part, tries to make coding javascript easier by including functions + properties to use. `$` will never equal an object because it isn't.. it's the start of a jquery function, `$('')` is an jquery object.. just read the docs ..

Comment: You are right, in my case `container` is a parameter of a function, and can take the value `$` or `$.find('.container')`. I just put here the case which is not working.

Comment: no.. you've defined `container` as `$('.container')` that's not a param for a function, that's a object.. if you want to create a dynamic function you want to look into `$(this)`

Comment: Ok, I have edited my post, hope it's clearer now

Comment: NB: I removed the "solution" section of your answer, as on StackOverflow that is not how it works. The Question area should be reserved for the question only, and the Answer area for answers only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. The way to detect that `container = $('.container')` did not yield a match, is not with `container === $`. Instead check the size of the jQuery object: `container.length === 0`

   *[After the last edit of your question, this point is no longer relevant: you removed `$('.container')` and now just tell us that `container === $` can be true].*
2. The jQuery function `find` needs the jQuery object -- on which the find should be performed -- as `this` value or it will not run correctly. But when you copy that function reference and call it without a `this`, the execution will fail. This is what happens in your case. You can use `bind` to get around this.

```js
const container = $('.container');
const find = (container.length ? container.find.bind(container) : $);

find('button').on('click', function() {
    console.log('hey!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <button>click me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to check if `container.length === 0`, I actually want to check if `container === $` as container can have two different values : `$` or `$('.container')`. But your answer worked, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, and I understand you don't want to make that comparison: I wrote that part of the answer before you removed the example on how you initialised `container`.